# Como importar CSS externo

Tags: sass, preprocessador, compass

Olá, estou usando o compass e gostaria de saber como eu posso importar um arquivo externo da minha pasta configurada para o sass.

Atualmente está assim o scss:

```
@import "../../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/reset";

$azul : #214d8f;

body {
  background-color: $azul;
}
```

A saída que ele me dá é essa:

```
@import url(../../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css); ...
```

O que preciso fazer é com que este angular-material.min.css seja de fato incluso no meu css final, e não apenas referenciado. Testei o `@embed`, mas também não deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

No StackOverflow (em inglês) eu havia feito esta mesma pergunta, comunicaram que já havia outro post similar com a solução.

**https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-css-importer**

Testei aqui e funcionou certinho, só não ficou muito legal (não sei o porquê) com o `angular-material.min.js`. Quando testei a versão não minificada funcionou certo.